# Date format is not working with dd(Int)-Month(String)-yyyy(Int)

Tags: php, date, datepicker

I have a form with some datepicker to select date fields. Here I have to save the date on database. the date format which I am using on jquery datepicker is " 12-Feb-2016". I want it to store it by reading the textbox value.

```
$posted['ad_close_date']. $ad_close_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $_POST['ad_close_date'])));
```

[image]

but the above code gives me the  result like this. **1970-01-01** , 
I don't know whats wrong in my code. How can I store it on database.

Comment: try using date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['ad_close_date'])); if you are passing  12-Feb-2016 else if u are passing unixtimestamp   date('Y-m-d', $_POST['ad_close_date']);

Comment: first one works , thank you for prompt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['ad_close_date']));
```

If you are passing `12-Feb-2016`, else if you are passing an unix timestamp:

```
date('Y-m-d', $_POST['ad_close_date']);`
```